# Excel nested if and or

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=IF(OR(C2<4)E2="IT"AND C2<2),"yes","no")
```

Basically Im trying to create a formula where if:

IF C2 < 4 then Yes, else No

OR

IF E2 = "IT" and C2 <2 then Yes, else No.

Im close, but hitting a wall
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you sure about criteria? If E2="IT" and C2<2 = TRUE, then C2<4 is also always TRUE, so in this case =IF(C2<4),"yes","no") would be enough

Answer (score 0):

AND is like OR and should be at the beginning with`()`

They both follow this schema: `AND(FirstTest,SecondTest,...)`

See [HERE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-if-with-and-or-and-not-functions-d895f58c-b36c-419e-b1f2-5c193a236d97)

```
=IF(OR(C2<4,AND(E2="IT", C2<2)),"yes","no")
```

But as @user11222393 stated in the comments, Since it will return `yes` for any value of `C2` that is less than `4` the `AND` is not needed, because C2 being less than `2` already satisfies the first.

Comment: Something is off with OP's criteria: OR(C2<4,AND(E2="IT", C2<2)) will always give same result as just C2<4

Comment: @user11222393, that is true.  I did not think about the logic itself, just how it should be written.

Comment: OK maybe I will have to two sperate columns. I need the logic

Comment: Then pull out the parts you need for each formula. @MattyS